# Symfony4 Element legend not allowed as child of element div in this context

Tags: html, css, symfony, symfony4, w3c-validation

Symfony is generating a W3C error and I don't know how to resolve it : 
Element legend not allowed as child of element div in this context

here is the HTML line : 
`<div class="form-group row"><legend class="col-form-label col-sm-2 col-form-label required">Date de naissance</legend><div class="col-sm-10"><div id="lessee_birthday" class="form-inline"><div class="sr-only">`
I think it's generated by the formType

```
$builder
        ->add('civility', ChoiceType::class, [
            'label' => 'Civilite',
            'choices' => [
                'Mr' => 'Mr',
                'Mme' => 'Mme',
                'Mlle' => 'Mlle',
            ]
        ])
        ->add('name', TextType::class, ['label' => 'Prénom'])
        ->add('lastname', TextType::class, ['label' => 'Nom'])
        ->add('birthday', BirthdayType::class, ['label' => 'Date de naissance']) //here is the problem
        ->add('placeOfBirth', TextType::class, ['label' => 'Lieu de naissance'])
        ->add('email', EmailType::class, ['label' => 'Adresse email'])
        ->add('phoneNumber', TelType::class, ['label' => 'Numéro de telephone'])
    ;
```

Answer (score 1):

According to the [specification](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/legend) `<legend>` tags belong directly underneath `<fieldset>` tags. You cannot mix them with `<div>` tags.

So you have to change in your templates how the `BirthdayType` field is rendered. Have a look at [How to Customize Form Rendering](https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/form_customization.html) in Symfony.

Comment: yeah I know, and I m checking this documentation again and again and again, but I don't find the solution, I tried different things, but not the good one

Comment: How do you render the form? Can you post the template? Did you tried to override the field's template as described [here](https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/form_themes.html#creating-a-form-theme-in-the-same-template-as-the-form), e.g. like `{% block birthday_widget %} ...`?